# Não consigo desenvolver alguém pode ajudar

Tags: c

A Caixa Econômica publicou os 20 números sorteados no concurso da MEGASORTE. Só ganha
quem acertar todos os 20 números. Escreva um programa que ajude a encontrar os sortudos ganhadores do
prêmio milionário. Após obter, via teclado, o valor do prêmio, os 20 números sorteados (digitados em
ordem crescente) e a quantidade de cartões (máximo de 100 cartões), serão introduzidos os dados de cada
cartão. Para cada cartão, serão lidos os números apostados (valores do tipo inteiro) digitados em ordem
crescente. Importante: em um único cartão são apostados, exatamente, 20 números. Para cada cartão
vencedor, deve ser impresso o seu código identificador (o número a que corresponde na entrada de dados,
sequencialmente numerados, o 1º. Cartão informado é o cartão 0). Ao final do programa, deve ser impresso
o valor rateado do prêmio ou uma mensagem informando que o prêmio acumulou, caso não haja vencedores.
O seu programa deve, OBRIGATORIAMENTE, usar uma matriz para armazenar os números marcados
em cada cartão e um vetor para os números sorteados.
a) Faça uma função para preencher os números sorteados
b) Faça uma função para preencher a matriz de apostas
c) Faça uma função para verificar e mostrar quais apostas acertaram os números sorteados
d) Faça uma função para mostrar o valor do prêmio para cada aposta vencedora
e) Faça um programa principal faça as chamadas das funções na ordem necessária para exibir uma
execução como a seguir (não é necessário criar um menu): (assumindo apenas 4 números, ao
invés dos 20 pedidos no enunciado):
Exemplo da execução do programa
Entre com o valor do premio: 1000
Entre com os numeros sorteados: 5 15 24 33
Entre com a quantidade de cartoes: 3
Entre com os numeros apostados no cartao com identificador 0: 5 15 24 33
Entre com os numeros apostados no cartao com identificador 1: 6 12 59 60
Entre com os numeros apostados no cartao com identificador 2: 5 15 24 33
Cartoes vencedores: 0, 2
Valor rateado do premio = 500.

Comment: Favor melhorar a pergunta original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/535641/